# How to get a list of all attachements urls for every post of a wordpress installation?

Tags: media, attachments

I'd like to retrieve a list of all attachment URLs for all posts of a website.

```
This would bring something like
http://example.com/mypost/attachment-1/
http://example.com/mypost/attachment-2/
http://example.com/anotherpost/attachment-deff/
http://example.com/post3/attachment-deff4/
```

Would it imply to use: wp_get_attachment_url

Comment: Every attachment has its own page. You can retrieve that page url using `get_permalink($attachment_id);`

Comment: You mean you want to get it from the builtin sitemap xml?